# Mongo X509 tls connection options

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to connect to mongo using Java driver with X509 auth with the tls options.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#tls-options

```
tls=true&tlsCertificateKeyFile=local.pem&tlsCertificateKeyFilePassword=
```

But, getting the warning.

```
2022-05-27T17:16:17.985Z    WARN    main    org.mongodb.driver.uri  Connection string contains unsupported option 'tlscafile'.
2022-05-27T17:16:17.985Z    WARN    main    org.mongodb.driver.uri  Connection string contains unsupported option 'tlscertificatekeyfilepassword'.
2022-05-27T17:16:17.986Z    WARN    main    org.mongodb.driver.uri  Connection string contains unsupported option 'tlscertificatekeyfile'.
```

Is this not supported yet in the driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These options are not supported via java connection string. See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-3066.

> Options the driver can't implement (Because TLS is configured in Java via system properties. Applications that want this behavior have to configure either those system properties or provide a custom SslContext to the driver via settings):

```
tlsAllowInvalidCertificates
tlsCAFile
tlsCertificateKeyFile
tlsCertificateKeyFilePassword
```

I'm not familar with java itself, but the description says that you should configure [SslContext](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/javadoc/com/mongodb/MongoClientOptions.html#getSslContext--) or system properties.
UPDATE: See [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.1/driver/tutorials/ssl/) about how it can be configured.

Comment: I dont see the option to set  tlsCAFile, tlsCertificateKeyFile thru the connection string. Looks like the Java driver doesnt support this.

Comment: this is what I said in the answer, you can specify this only via system properties or SslContext

Comment: Sorry, I was confused with the UPDATE you made.